# What is an integrable system?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm struggling to understand the concept of integrable systems (and/or integrability). I have had a look and a lot of places mention how there is no formal definition, or how it cannot be properly defined. Is this true?

I'm doing a year long project for my dissertation. I will mainly be studying the Hirota Method if that helps? I have been reading some material that is meant to help, and it mentions both the non-linear Schrödinger and the Korteweg-de Vries equations. Hope that helps.

Comment: Here's a similar question asked on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6379/what-is-an-integrable-system

Comment: I think “integrability” should be considered analogous to other vaguely defined notions in math, like “nice function” or “closed form solution”; it describes something which is dependent on context and psychology rather than a precise mathematical concept.